# Cannot find or run Tor Browser on Ubuntu 12.05 after installing it

Tags: debian, tor

I just installed Tor Browser on UBUNTU 12.05 (PRECISE) following the instructions from TOR site about using the DEBIAN repository instead of UBUNTU repository. It went fine up to point where I enter `sudo apt-get install tor` and that completed fine too. The instructions said TOR is now installed and running.

The problem is I cannot find or run the TOR Browser on the system. I searched the entire system using `find / -name tor*` and I don't see any tor browser to run.

Meanwhile if I just download and extract the bundle I could get it running through a terminal session without any of the DEBIAN part.

I just don't understand why following the official instructions and getting success all the way does not get me any tor browser that I can find? 
Can anyone advise me on this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you use Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: The title of the question explicitly states "Ubuntu 12.05".

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) and installed tor it will not give you tor browser.You will also need to configure your applications to use tor as given in the [step 2](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en#using).

As suggested in the above link, if you want to just surf the web anonymously then installing tor browser directly from the [bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) (as you did the second time) is the right thing to do.